# Title attribute of HTML still render although it has remove in mustache file

Tags: php, html, moodle, mustache

I try to remove the title attribute of tag a in the mustache template of moodle framework. But somehow, it still renders the title attribute inside the tag "a" without value or empty value.

```
<h3 class="lorem-value"><a href="{{url}}">{{{title}}}</a></h3>
```

```html
<h3 class="lorem-value"><a href="lorem-value" title>Lorem title in there</a></h3>
```

So, what happened in there? How can we fix that?
Thanks

Comment: Either purge the cache from the moodle development section in the site administration. Or if you are in a development environment you can enable the design mode from the appearance section in the site administration menu. Also, you can update your `config.php` file to disable cache for js and theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you are looking at the cached version of the template or the page uses the template. You have different options to see the new changes taking place.

- If you are making changes in a production server (which is not recommended) you can use the web interface or the admin CLI to purge caches. From your terminal execute `php admin/cli/purgecaches.php` of course you have to be in your Moodle root directory.
  [image: Purge cache from web interface]
- Enable design mode from the appearance theme setting page.
  [image: Design mode theme setting page]
- Disable cache from `config.php` file.

  ```
  // Prevent Template caching
  $CFG->cachetemplates = false; // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
  ```